# Refresh ng-repeat rows when new data is added to source using parse.com

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this `AngularJS` controller which fetches data from a class I have created on parse.com

```
app.controller('dataCtrl', function($scope) {

    var MarketingData = Parse.Object.extend('MarketingData');
    
    var query = new Parse.Query(MarketingData);

    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.resultData = results.map(function(obj) {
                    return {
                        startDate: obj.get('StartDate'),
                        endDate: obj.get('EndDate'),
                        investment: obj.get('Investment'),
                        format: obj.get('Format'),
                        partner: obj.get('Partner'),
                        purpose: obj.get('Purpose')
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Together with this `HTML`

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in resultData">
    <td>{{x.startDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
    <td>{{x.endDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
    <td>{{x.investment}}</td>
    <td>{{x.format}}</td>
    <td>{{x.partner}}</td>
    <td>{{x.purpose}}</td>
</tr>
```

How can I bind a button to refresh the rows with new data (new rows)? I'm fairly new to both parse.com and AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your code to get data inside a function, then call that function when you press on the refresh button.

I'd write it like it :

```
app.controller('dataCtrl', function($scope) {

function getData() {
    var MarketingData = Parse.Object.extend('MarketingData');

    var query = new Parse.Query(MarketingData);

    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.resultData = results.map(....);
            });
        });
    });
};

getData(); //Get data on launch

$scope.refreshData = function() { 
    getData();
}

});
```

In the HTML, just add :

```
<button value="Refresh" ng-click="getData()"></button>
```

Comment: Just had to change `<button value="Refresh" ng-click="refreshData()"></button>` and it worked. Thank's!